# React Native: Unable to pass params using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a top level stack navigator:

```
const routeConfiguration = {
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Home: { screen: HomeWrapper,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }    
    },
    UserInfo: { screen: UserFormsTabBar, 
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        } 
    },
    Profile: { screen: ProfilePage } 
}
```

in `Profile` I am trying to pass params to `UserInfo` which is a nested TabNavigator. Each screen of this Tab Navigator is in turn a `StackNavigator`  Not to forget to mention, all wrapped with `Redux`.

in Profile:

```
goToTabs = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('UserInfo', {isComingFromProfile: true})
}
```

in UserInfo, first Tab screen:

```
class FirstTab extends Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props);

       console.log('passed params: ', props.navigation.state.isComingFromProfile)

    }
}
```

The above `console.log` returns `undefined` , the `props.navigation.state` only has `key` and `routeName`. 
I tried doing this, also no use:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('UserInfo', {}, { type: 'Navigate', routeName: 'PersonalTab', params: {isFromEdit: true} })
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `this.props.navigation.state.isComingFromProfile` in `componentDidMount()`? What's the output?

Comment: I found the problem by testing with another screen in Top Level Stack, it worked fine. The problem is that each tab screen in `UserInfo` is a `StackNavigator` , so when I log in `FirstTab` (which is actually a part of its own stack) , There no Params, because it somehow not passed to it, this is what i am assuming at the moment anyway

Comment: I have the same problem. state.params is undefined. It just sucks. I tried everything and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is:

```
props.navigation.state.params.isComingFromProfile
```